# VB.NET: API callback - get caller information

Tags: vb.net, api, parameters, callback

I am accessing a data service that provides an .NET api to retrieve market data. Basically, the request looks like this (simpliefied)...

```
For Each myID in myListofIDs
     myRequest = myDataService.Realtime.GetID(myID, AddressOf ReturnDataFunction, AddressOf ReturnErrorFunction)
Next
```

I send multiple requests in the same thread, the requests are then done performed assynchronously by the API. At the end the data is recieved from the callbackbackfunction and I can store it.

However, here's my problem: None of the callback functions returns the original IDs but only the data. If I get an error and "ReturnErrorFunction" is called, the only information I get from the error message is, that "the ID cannot be found" - but it wont tell me which ID has caused the error.

Is there any information to include an additional paramater to the callback definition in my code or is there a way to trace the original function that started the call?

Would be glad if you can tell me if I have any options here to avoid this problem... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do something like this:

```
myRequest = myDataService.Realtime.GetID(myID, 
                                         AddressOf ReturnDataFunction,
                                         Sub(myResult As String)
                                             Call ReturnErrorFunction(myResult, myID)
                                         End Sub)
```

There are some potential technical issues in the event that the callback is stored and potentially called later, after the loop concludes, but I won't get into those unless it's actually relevant to you.

Comment: Thanks, Craig - that's exactly what I need. However, the callback function receives an argument from the dataservice. Do you have an idea how I can it accordingly? The current signature of the callback function looks like following, so I would need to define the callback to include the argument...

<code>
    Sub ReturnErrorFunction(myResult as String)

Comment: I've revised the answer to match your actual callback signature.

Comment: Thanks, mate. That was exactly what I was looking for!